# add ui bootstrap directive to an html dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to add popover to a div. However, I need to add it dynamically.

```
<div popover="Please select from dropdown">foo foo foo</div>
```

I've tried ng-class but looks like it's not a class. I tried ng-attr-hidden but also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the popover content in your controller and then apply it:

```
<div popover="{{dynamicPopover}}">Some text</div>
```

if dynamicPopover is empty, then there is no popover displayed

This is actually almost exactly the same example as they use in the docs ([link](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover))

Comment: Never thought of that! I do that always. I'll try it now :)

Comment: Havvy, just search popover from this link - http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/